# Microsoft Application Virtualization - Export to Excel

Tags: excel, export, virtualization

It is possible to add 'Export to Excel' context menu item [as shown here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-export-to-microsoft-excel-to-the-right-click-menu-in-internet-explorer/)

This is done by adding `res://C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\EXCEL.EXE/3000` via regedit.

Is it possible to do the same with Microsoft Application Virtualization?

The problem is that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12` is empty and does not contain an `excel.exe` file.

Comment: Office 2010 deployed by using Microsoft Application Virtualization (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602185.aspx). That is why there is no excel.exe on local machine

Comment: Right... so what's the path to excel.exe as far as the client is concerned?

Comment: Sorry, have no access to client machine right now. Do you mean that i should put the actual path of the virtual application into regedit? Try it tomorrow =)

Comment: try  boxedapp. it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting the path to `excel.exe` from what the client sees.